# Why is not the react style being removed when the component is unmounted?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have 2 pages:

- Home (React Class Component)
- CreatePost (React Functional Component)

Both of them have a style class with the same name '.Grid'.

When I'm in the CreatePost page and go to the Home page then the Home Page keep the .Grid from the CreatePost page.

**Should not the styles be removed when the React functional component is unmounted (when I exited the page)?**

I'm importing the styles like '`import ./Home.css`' and '`import ./CreatePost.css`'

Comment: can you provide some code for both of your components, help us help you.

Comment: Webpack will typically bundle all the stylesheets into one file which will be loaded on initial page load. It's probably possible to use code splitting to load styles on demand, but in that case you might want to use some css in js library instead.

Comment: Your options is to either manually make sure that you don't reuse class names, or to use more specific selectors eg. `.Posts .Grid` `main>.Grid` etc. Or to use a css in js framework such as emotion. I think emotion will rewrite your original class names to ensure that there are no unintended name collisions.

Answer (score 0):

React won't remove the CSS you import, since it is not React component.
You can consider using styled-component.